# mocking a class instance in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

am trying to mock a class instance while testing a method something like below

```
source
    main_proc.py
    devinstance.py
    prodinstance.py
    requirements.txt
    host.json
```

main_proc.py

```
def get_instance(self)
    ins = None
    env = os.getenv('env', 'dev')
    if env == 'dev':
        ins = DevInstance()
    else:
        ins = ProdInstance()
    return ins
```

Sample DevInstance class
devinstance.py

```
class DevInstance:
    def __init__(self):
        self.eh_client = dict()
        self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
        try:
            
                client = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=self.secrets_dict[value],
                                                                       eventhub_name=names[i], http_proxy=HTTP_PROXY)
                
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            raise e
```

testing the get instance like below as my intension is to mock the entire DevInstance class obj. both files are in the same module.

```
@mock.patch("devinstance.DevInstance")
def test_get_instance(self, devins):
    
        # Act
        devins.return_value = MagicMock()

        result = get_instance()

        # Assert
        assert result is not None
```

Can anyone help me how this can be acheived?

Comment: In what module is `get_event_processor` defined? Have you read through [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)?

Comment: both files are in the same module. can check updated version

Comment: Do you mean files or functions?

Comment: both are in same module. Edited the question with the file structure.

Comment: In which file is `get_event_processor` defined?

Comment: sorry, am intended to test get_instance() method in which the DevInstance is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to patch where the object is being looked up (see the [Where to patch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)).

If you're testing `get_instance` in `main_proc`, then you need to patch where `DevInstance` is imported in `main_proc`.

For example, if you're importing it with `from devinstance import DevInstance`, then you need to patch it with  `@mock.patch("main_proc.DevInstance")`.

Otherwise, if you're importing it with `import devinstance`, then you need to patch it with  `@mock.patch("main_proc.devinstance.DevInstance")`.

Comment: Thanks for providing documentation which helped me to know in detailing